# Unmounting HTC device takes forever

Tags: block-device, unmounting

Not sure if should post this on [Android SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) because I don't think this is directly related to the Android OS. On my system I manually `mount` and `umount` my HTC device with these options in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=3465-3762 /mnt/htc auto gid=100,umask=002,noauto,user,rw,exec 0 0
```

This works fine when modifying small amounts of data on the SD card, but whenever I copy e.g. a couple of music albums encoded in FLAC from another device - unmounting the SD card seems to take forever:

```
$ time umount /mnt/htc/
real    1m17.195s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.237s
```

Is this time proportional to the amount of data modified? Should it take this long to unmount it anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's to do with the kernel doing a lot of buffering, including buffering writes to your device.

If you issue:

```
cp large_file /mnt/htc/
```

`cp` will return as soon as it has finished `write`ing the data, but (for reasonably "slow" devices/connections) well before that data has actually been written. (Unless `cp` or the tool you use itself issues `fsync` or similar calls to wait for the actual data to have hit the drive - some graphical file managers do this, some tools have options you can use to control whether they do or not.)

`unmount` flushes the write buffers before it "detaches" the device so that you don't lose data. It can take a lot of time if the kernel buffered a lot of data, and the actual writes are slow.

Try to run something like `iostat 2` (part of the `sysstat`) in a terminal while you do the copy and the `unmount`, you should see write I/O up until the point `unmount` returns.

Comment: So this also has to do with the speed of the device connection/bus right? I'm using the standard micro USB 2.0 cable so this should be sufficient for transfering maybe smaller files.

Comment: Yes, it has a lot do do with how fast the data goes to the device. Say you copy a 1MB file. The kernel can (probably) cache all that, so `cp` will return instantly. If your device (or the bus you're using) only does 1KB/s transfers, `unmount` will take approx 1024s to complete. If your device is a fast disk system with a high bandwidth bus (says SAS), the writeout will be done before you're finished typing `unm`.